# mysql NOW() and php date() are different in the same timezone

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

After struggling for hours on this timezone issue, I got PHP and mysql set to the same time zone (America/New_York). I did this by

after making sql connection:     `SET time_zone = 'America/New_York'`

in php page: `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`

However, when I printed NOW() and date(), I get:

```
mysql NOW(): 2013-12-21 02:58:10 
php DATE(): 2013-12-21 03:01:48
```

I thought setting mysql and php to the same timezone will do the trick, but the weird 3 minutes and 38 seconds offset really throws me off. I wanted to do a query to select activities in the last minute via

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE activity_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)
```

but activity_time was set using php's date() function, so that comparison doesn't work. The ugly workaround that I can think of is by taking the time difference (3 minutes and 38 seconds difference. really?) into into account, view that time difference as 218 seconds, and do

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE activity_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 298 SECOND)
```

But in an ideal world I want to get mysql NOW() and PHP date() to display the same time in the same timezone. Is that possible?

Comment: the problem is you never execute the scripts at the same time

Comment: You have not indicated whether the MySQL server and the php box are the same... Could be different servers. Alternately, are you using a script that takes that long to run such that the times when you run NOW() and date() are different?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: Dreamhost hosts my website and my database, so I believe they're the same server? At least I'd expect the time on them to be same. 
I have NOW() and date() running one line after another. 1 second difference is okay, but 218 seconds is odd.

Comment: the php and the sql, each run by its side are two separate processes and occur in different times inclusive if you run them simultaneously

Comment: "Believe" isn't good enough.

Comment: @Emilio's comment explained what might be going on. Instead of modifying the sql, I changed the php code to store NOW() time, and this works. Thanks guys!